# NullPointerException in array.length Java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I've been getting an NPE whenever I try to access my array. Even calling for the .length attribute gives me an NPE. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my constructor and the method that keeps failing.

```
public SkierList() {
    Skier[] skiers= new Skier[INITIAL_CAP];
    for (int i = 0; i < skiers.length; i++){
        skiers[i] = new Skier("");
    }
    int count = 0;
    
}

public void add(Skier newSkier) {   
    if (this.size() < skiers.length)
    {
        skiers[count] = new Skier(newSkier.getName(), newSkier.getLevel());
        count++;
    }
}
```

The code compiles but throws the NPE at skiers.length

Comment: why do you have Skier defined as an array, and as an object? makes no sense

Comment: you should be defining your array as a global array, and make sure you dont name objects after your array

Comment: Look up variable shadowing because that is exactly what you're doing. You've likely already got a skiers field that you're not showing us (else the code wouldn't compile), but you're shadowing it by re-declaring it in the constructor. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Define skier globally:

```
public Skier[] skiers= new Skier[INITIAL_CAP];
```

Comment: He already defines skier globally, else the code wouldn't compile. But he doesn't initialize the variable in the class scope since he's shadowing the variable.

Comment: But he has it in the SkierList()

Comment: Yes he does, but if he didn't also declare (but not initialize it) within the class, the code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You must be shadowing the variable by redeclaring it in the constructor. Don't do that as it leaves the field null. So not this:

```
public class SkierList() {
    private Skier[] skiers; // this remains null

    public SkierList() {
        // you're re-declaring the skiers variable here
        // so only this local variable is non-null
        Skier[] skiers= new Skier[INITIAL_CAP];

        // ....
    }
}
```

But rather

```
public class SkierList() {
    private Skier[] skiers; 

    public SkierList() {
        // Skier[] skiers= new Skier[INITIAL_CAP]; // Don't do this
        skiers = new Skier[INITIAL_CAP];  // note the difference
    }
}
```

or

```
public class SkierList() {
    private Skier[] skiers = new Skier[INITIAL_CAP];

    public SkierList() {
        // Skier[] skiers= new Skier[INITIAL_CAP];
    }
}
```