# Swing - JTable and DefaultTableModel references always return null

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm writing an app that reads a series of strings from a virtual COM port and then displays those strings in a table so the user can edit them and export back out the COM port. I am using Swing with JTable and DefaultTableModel. I can initialize the table OK and display dummy data, but am unable to use fireTableDataChanged() to update the table data with the values read from the serial port.

```
public class SwingMain extends JFrame {
    ...
    private JScrollPane lensListScroller;
    private JPanel listPane;
    private static JTable workListTable;
    private static DefaultTableModel workListModel;
    private static String[] columnNames = {"Manufacturer", "Series", "Focal Length", "Status"};
    static Object[][] lensTableData;
    ...

    public SwingMain() {
        ...
        // dummy data to populate the table at the beginning
        Object[][] lensTableData = {{"Angenieux", "Optimo", "24-290mm", "Calibrated: F | Mylist: A"}};
        DefaultTableModel workListModel = new DefaultTableModel(lensTableData, columnNames);
        JTable workListTable = new JTable(workListModel);

        // Scroll pane for Lens Work List
        JScrollPane lensListScroller = new JScrollPane(workListTable);

        JPanel listPane = new JPanel();
        listPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Work List");
    }
    ...
}
```

That all works fine for showing the table initially. I run into problems when I try to add the imported data to the `DefaultTableModel workListModel`:

```
public class SwingMain extends JFrame {
    ...
    private static void receiveLensData(String text) throws SerialPortException {
        System.out.println("receiveLensData: " + text);
        if (!isConnected) {
            if (text.contains("Hand")) {
                System.out.println("Hand detected");
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
        else {
            if (transfer) {
                if (!startLensRx) {
                        ...
                        lensTableData = new Object[numLenses][4];
                } else {
                    if (text.contains(EOTStr)) {
                        System.out.println("EOT detected");
                        serialPort.writeBytes(ACK_SYN);
                        transfer = false;
                        startLensRx = false;
                        currentLens = 0;
                        progressBar.setVisible(false);
                        addLensesToWorkList(); // <-- calling the function to populate the table
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Lens " + currentLens + " of " + numLenses + ": " + text);
                        lensArray.add(text);
                        progressBar.setValue(currentLens);
                        currentLens += 1;
                        serialPort.writeBytes(ACK);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addLensesToWorkList() {
        for (int i=0; i < lensArray.size(); i++) {
            // add the imported string to the Object[][] that the table model was declared with
            lensTableData[i] = parseLensLine(lensArray.get(i));
        }

        // after updating lensTableData, I want to tell the table model that the dataset has changed. 
        // But workListModel and workListTable always are null:
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){
            workListModel.fireTableDataChanged();  // <-NullPointerException here
        }});
    }
}
```

I can tell that the `Object[][] lensTableData` is getting populated correctly, but I'm unable to reference the table (`workListTable`) or its model (`workListModel`) since they always return `null` when I try to reference them from within `addLensesToWorkList()` method.

I imagine I'm just missing something in the initial declaration of the table and/or model. Or do I need to create a new table/model after importing the data and then add that table to my `JScrollPane`? I'm new to Java dev for desktop. Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: Please show code where you are calling `addLensesToWorkList()`

Comment: `static`? You really don't want to do that.

Comment: You would debug this as you would any other NullPointerException. Please read the duplicate as it will show you the steps that you need to follow.

Comment: You're shadowing the workListModel variable. Don't do that. Don't re-declare it in the constructor.  i.e., don't do `Foo foo = new Foo();` in the constructor or method but rather `foo = new Foo();` -- see the difference?

Comment: For similar error see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34979808/522444)

Comment: Thanks for those pointers. What should I be declaring `static`? If I don't declare `workListTable` and `workListModel` as `static`, I get an error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field workListModel`

Comment: Removing the variable shadowing and declaring `workListModel` and `workListTable` as `public static` seems to have worked. Should I be declaring those `static`?

Comment: No, none of those fields should be static. You may wish to study a decent book or chapter on OOPs as it applies to Java programming since this concept is too key and too intrinsic to Java programming to ignore.

Comment: `"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field workListModel"` -- especially if you don't see that you're fixing this problem the exact wrong way.

Comment: OK, understood, any recommendations?